# Why are my questions being down voted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

This is my reputation page links: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/93616/sawarnik?tab=reputation .Click under today, and you will know why. These question are not bad and inactive, and I do not understand why they are being serially down voted now?

Comment: Cereal downvotes (:P). Wait till 9:30 IST and all the downvotes would eventually be reversed. There is an automated script that detects such downvotes.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: _Possible_ serial downvotes. Even I, as a ♦-moderator, do not have enough information to determine this. But you are correct, _if_ the system detects this as serial downvoting, these votes will be invalidated when the automated script runs next.  (See [MSO serial voting faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/214632).)

Comment: (While I don't see what's wrong with these questions and) 3 downvotes surely are frustrating, but calling it 'serial downvoting' is an exaggeration, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, serial downvoting does not mean your answers are bad.  As noted, serial downvotes (if that is what these are) will be reversed automatically once a day.

But three downvotes is nothing:  a week ago I had 20 of my answers downvoted within a period of 7 minutes.  The lost reputation was restored automatically by the next morning.

[image: graph]